# Get a song datas and put it in a share button

Tags: wordpress, button, audio, share, audio-player

```
<ul id="audio-player-playlist">    
<li class="playlist_item" data-song_title="title" data-song_artwork="" data-song_file="http://example.com/mysong.mp3" data-song_artist="Artist"></li>
<li class="playlist_item" data-song_title="title" data-song_artwork="" data-song_file="http://example.com/mysong.mp3" data-song_artist="Artist"></li>
<li class="playlist_item current" data-song_title="title" data-song_artwork="" data-song_file="http://example.com/mysong.mp3" data-song_artist="Artist"></li>
</ul>
```

This is the list generated by my audio player. When I click play, the `playlist_item_current` class is added to the song that's playing.

The thing is I want the users the be able to share the song playing. How can I get the current song's data and put it in my share button?

Comment: are you using javascript? Which code is adding the "current" class? Also what "share" code do you already have?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the music player you are using is created in javascript & you probably are already using jQuery as well so in that case:

in jQuery you can easily do the following to retreive the songname from the currently playing song:

```
$('.playlist_item.current').data('song_title');
```

For the artist:

```
$('.playlist_item.current').data('song_artist');
```

These functions would return the necessary data.